# Redirecting all commands stdout/stderr to a log file from within a script

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, stdout, stderr

I've read how to log certain scripts or commands individually, but nothing on how to log all commands from within a BASH shell. What I want to do is:

- User runs script. (script logs stdout/stderr from now on to a logfile)
- User does other stuff/runs other commands/echoes/etc and all of these are logged in logfile.

A less wordy / more codey example:

**exec > >(tee logfile.log)** when typed in by the user does exactly what I want to do. It logs stdout to logfile.log and will continue to do so until the bash shell is closed. However, running this very command as a script does not do this. I want it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this in a script that runs under its own shell (i.e. it starts with `#!/bin/bash` and you `chmod +x` and invoke it like an executable).  The redirect affects the subshell but it can't reach the parent to do what you want.  You can `.` the file (as in `. ./myscript.sh`) which will execute the commands *in your shell* and then you can redirect things as you want.

The other way to do it would be for your script to start a subshell itself (which would inherit stdin, stdout, stderr).  This is what the `script` command does.  It logs everything to a file named (by default) `typescript` until the user exits the subshell.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the 'script' command, which I have found to be quite handy!

Answer (score 1):

$ bash | tee /tmp/logs/logfile.txt

$ ls /tmp/logs

logfile.txt

$ < CTRL-D>

exit

$ cat /tmp/logs/logfile.txt

logfile.txt

---

if you're looking for just stdout then this seems to work. If you want stdin/stdout then script is the way to go as mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

How about an alias?

```
alias Start-Script='script logfile.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, if someone wants to do this to start a daemon (background process), i'd suggest to look at the excellent [daemonize](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/).

`daemonize` allows you to start a process from a certain directory (without cd'ing), redirecting stdout, redirecting stderr, writing a pidfile or lockfile, and run as a certain user. This is very useful eg. when writing your own small init script.

synopsis from the [man page](http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/daemonize.html) tells you most about its quite straightforward usage:

```
daemonize [-a] [-c directory] [-e stderr] [-o stdout] [-p pidfile] [-l lockfile] [-u user] [-v] path [arg] ...
```